# Sitemap using OOTB in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, portalsitemapprovider

I am having a site with as many as 15 web part pages in it. I want to create a site map for the site. Is it possible with OOTB features? I am using SharePoint 2010. Any suggestions on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one built in: **SharePoint 2010 > Edit > Insert > Web Part > Content Rollup > Table of Contents**.

Table of Contents webpart is used to show Sub Sites, Library, Lists, Discussions, etc...

May be it can solve your problem.

**UPDATED**

If you want to use webparts than below are the best solutions available.

[How to create a SharePoint visual site map using Smart Art and SharePoint Designer](http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2011/10/23/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-visual-site-map-using-smart-art-and-sharepoint-designer/) - The best i got

[Site Map Web Part (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82664/Site-Map-Web-Part-SharePoint-Server)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Hardik I tried Table of contents earlier but am looking for something which shows my site pages names as index and clicked on them should take me to those respected pages. This should be on the separate page of the site.

Comment: Than you must have to use webpart for it. As you asked for OOTB solution, I had tried to give you the solution otherwise webpart is the only way by which you can get pages in sitemap.

Comment: If you need help to get sitemap webpart than i can suggest you. :)

Comment: What do you need? Have you tried this link?...https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Table-of-Contents-Web-Part-to-display-navigation-on-a-Web-page-49963232-d634-44de-8502-2294fd5904a0

Comment: I am trying to show my web part pages(Names) on the site map like an index and once clicked on the names it should take me to respective page. I tried the table of contents it just shows like site pages and not the pages present in the site which I created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41211/discussion-between-user2314241-and-hardik).